# Control body class when open/close aside menu

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

Using the concept described on w3schools (can't paste 2 links yet :/, if google *'w3schools how to js sidenav'*, is the first result). I'd like to control the body style to make the Sidenav off canvas push effect.

```css
body{
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  &.aside-open{
    margin-left:-320px;
    margin-right:320px;

    @media(max-width: 991px){
      margin-left:-240px;
      margin-right:240px;
    }
  }
}
```

It works on the opening but the closing is not working, it seems to be stacking the animations (wait until the aside to be closed to remove the body 'aside-open' class), as proven on this pen http://codepen.io/huggaf/pen/XKYoKW/

Stack:

- angular v1.5.5
- angular-animate v1.5.5
- angular-strap v2.3.6
- twitter-bootstrap v3.3.5
- angular-motion v0.4.4
- bootstrap-additions v0.3.1

I did a test adding to the body the class 'aside-closing' inside the hide function...

```js
$modal.hide = function() {
  if (!$modal.$isShown) return;
  bodyElement.addClass(options.prefixClass + '-closing');
  //...
```

... and removing it on the leaveAnimateCallback function...

```js
function leaveAnimateCallback() {
  scope.$emit(options.prefixEvent + '.hide', $modal);
  bodyElement.removeClass(options.prefixClass + '-open');
  bodyElement.removeClass(options.prefixClass + '-closing');
  //...
```

```css
body{
  &.aside-open{
    &.aside-closing{
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

... and it worked perfectly

**Is there a different approach to do this off canvas push?**

If anyone could enlighten me on the matter I'd appreciate it very much. :D